# Хранение данных в сессиях

Tags: php, сессия, меню

Сайт имеет одинаковые пункты меню на всех страницах и контактные данные (адрес, телефон, почта). Подскажите, пожалуйста, нормально ли хранить пункты меню и контакты в сессиях php, чтобы не делать запросы к бд каждый раз? Будет ли такое меню видно поисковым роботам?

Comment: Зачем? Если у вас меню не состоит из несколько тыс. элементов то нет смысла. Если вас волнует только эти запросы, и если они оптимально написаны(SQL) то никакой нагрузки не будет на сервере.

Comment: Нет смысла использовать сессии для кэширования, когда можно взять нормальный инструмент для кэширования (memcached, redis). А если SQL-запросы простые, до делать кэширование в общем-то совсем нет смысла

Comment: А поисковым роботом видно то, что вы выводите в html-коде в ответ на запрос. А как вы создаёте html-код, не имеет абсолютно никакого значения — какая разница, если результат одинаковый?